# Java polymorpshim: Array of Object

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

I am working on a class assignment that got me stuck for weeks now. I am wondering if someone can illustrate how I can find the solution.

I am working with three classes: Triangle, Circle and Rectangle.
An a abstract class: Shape

The constructor for each object:

- Triangle: public Triangle(Position pos, String fillColor, String lineColor,
  double side)
- Circle:  public Circle(Position pos, String fillColor, String lineColor,
  double radius)
- Rectangle: public Rectangle(Position pos, String fillColor, String lineColor,
  double width, double height)

The assignment is asking to:

1. Add a new class called ShapeArray. This class will also have a main method, and It will also prompt the user for a given arraySize(between 2 and 20),then it will create an array that will contain objects of typeTriangle,Circle, and Rectangle. The size of the array is arraySize.
   2..Populate this array randomly with objects that can be of any of the following types: Triangle, Circle, and Rectangle. The state of each object(e.g.,position, or radius, etc.) is also randomly assigned.

I cannot seem to figure out how I can create and fill an array of different object types(rectangle, circle and triangle) using a loop and at the same generating random value for each the object parameters at the constructor level.

I create some of the parameters but could not create random string parameter for linecolor and fillColor parameters.

This is what I came up with:

```
package homework.session10;
import java.util.*;

public class ShapeArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Please pick a number between 2-20 for the array size");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        int arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();

        ShapeArray [] shapeArray = new ShapeArray[arraySize];

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int posX = rnd.nextInt(11);
        int posY = rnd.nextInt(11);
        double recWidth = rnd.nextDouble(11.0);
        double recHeight = rnd.nextDouble(11.0);
        double cirRadius = rnd.nextDouble(11.0);
        double triSide = rnd.nextDouble(11.0);

        String fillColorObject = keyboard.next();
        String lineColorObject = keyboard.next();

        Position position1 = new Position(posX,posY);



       //ShapeArray

    }



    public void sortShape(Figure[] array1){
        Arrays.sort(array1);
    }

    public void findShape(Figure[] array2 ){

    }
}
```

Comment: `using a loop` Well, you don't have a loop at all.  You have got the create an array part correct, so next you should attempt the loop.  Hint: how do you normally loop over an array?  Start there.

Comment: What is a `Figure` ?  Hint: for your code to work you will need to have a common base class or interface.  Your title even monetions `Polymorphism`

Comment: `And a abstract class: Shape` Oops, I take that back.  The array creation is not correct.  You have an array of ShapeArray, but that's just your main class.  You'll need an array of Shape, your base class.  Try that instead, then start on the loop.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Figure is the interface.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this. Create a parent class in which the Rectangle, Circle, and Triangle will have common ancestor class:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    protected Position pos;
    protected String fillColor;
    protected String lineColor;
    protected double side;

public Shape(Position pos, String fillColor, String lineColor, double side) 
{
    this.pos = pos;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    this.lineColor = lineColor;
    this.side = side;
}}
```

then for each shape, create a separate class each, inheriting from abstract Shape class

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
public Rectangle(Position pos, String fillColor, String lineColor, double side){
    super(pos,fillColor,lineColor,side);
}}
```

(do the rest for other shapes, Circle and Triangle)

```
class ShapeArray{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int arraySize = keyboard.nextInt();
    Shape[] shapes = new Shape[arraySize];

  //your code to set random values

    for(int i = 0; i< arraySize;i++){
        shapes[i] = new Rectangle(new Position(1,2),"red","blue",2.0);
    }
}}
```

the part `shapes[i] = new Rectangle(new Position(1,2),"red","blue",2.0);`
is what the "polymorphism" refers to. As long as the class inherits from a parent class (Shape), that subclass (Rectangle) is allowed to be assigned to its parent class.